# Angular2 extract json from error

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm wrinting a pice of Angular2 code that interacts with a server which returns a json with http error codes such as 404 or 401.
I can't find a way to read the json out of the error response.
I can't use .map() since there is no data on normal response.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject: Response) => {
      this.http.request(new Request(requestoptions))
          .subscribe(
          data => {resolve()},
          error => { error.json() } //<-- No json()
          )
       };
```

How handle this?

Comment: check [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#error-handling) on how to handle errors while Http Call.

Comment: try error => console.log(error), The error object response may not be a json object. What's the api send code look like?

Comment: The error code contains a json object  ( i see this in the http response in the browser)

Comment: @ApriOri I'm facing your same problem: did you figure out how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by trying to parse only http codes that contain response.
This sample code may help others:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.httpProvider.login(url, credentials)
    .map(res => {
      //avoid parsing the response from the server for some requests since it's not a valid json
      if (res.status >= 400 && res.status < 500) {
        return res.json();
      }
      else return res;
    })
    .subscribe(
      data => {
      },
      error => {
        switch (error.status) {
          case 400:
          case 401:
            let erromsg: string = this.parseServerError(error);
            reject(erromsg);
            break;
          case 404:
          case 500:
            reject("Server error");
            break;

          default:
            reject("Network Error");
        }
      }
    );
});




parseServerError(error): string {
  try {
    let message = error.json().message[0].description;
    return message;
  } catch (e) {
    return "Undefined error";
  }
}
```